# How to update Node from 6.4.0 to 6.5.0 via apt?

Tags: apt, 16.04, nodejs

How do I update Node `6.4.0` to `6.5.0` on Ubuntu 16.04 via `apt` package manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider adding the node sources ppa to your set up. There are instructions [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#manual-installation).

You could also try [nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) which is a non-apt way managing the versions of node on your system. Running `sudo nave usemain 6.5.0` will install `6.5.0` to your system folders though I'd recommend using the `nave.sh` sub-shell approach to access different versions of node without doing central installs.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [nvm (node version manager)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) due to its flexibility and it allows you to easily switch versions.

It's simple to install; run:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`

then:

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm`

once it's installed (restart session if necessary), install and switch version by running these simple commands:

`nvm install 9 # will install version 9 of node
nvm use 9 # will switch to version 9
nvm alias default 9 # will use version by default upon boot`